# Theory: C# Sockets, Sending Serialized Objects Across a Network

Tags: c#, sockets, serialization

I want to build a server/client engine for a game that I will eventually be making.

While planning, I find that I'm stuck on one aspect: Sending objects across a network.

My goals for the client/server are:

- The client/server that I am describing is a 'world' server, and thus will use TCP to communicate.
- The server and/or client must be able to send any serializable object to eachother, and the receiver must be able to deserialize it on their end.
- The serialization method preferred would be binary.

However, I don't know how to send serialized data over a network socket. Sending a string is easy... You can simply append a terminator string to the end and wait for that to be received. I don't know how you can do something equivalent with objects; so any ideas/help/tutorials will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you thought of using WCF to do all this?

Comment: I am investigating it currently, yes. But I've not reached a conclusion yet. :)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but one vastly accepted standard for sending binary Data is encoding it base64 and decoding that at the other endpoint...Basically, it's sending terminated strings again...

Comment: Sebastian; would I append a '0' character to the end? Or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm biased (as the author), but protobuf-net would be an excellent fix here:

- binary, efficient (both CPU and bandwidth) format
- very version tolerant
- cross-platform (protobuf)

In particular, the `SerializeWithLengthPrefix` and `DeserializeWithLengthPrefix` (etc) are well-suited to socket use, as this handles the segmentation of messages for you. If you want, you can also use a variant here (and the non-generic API) to send any of a *range* of messages and have it recognise the message type based on a pre-defined number you think of.

This way, the library does all the worrying about getting the object onto the wire. The only sticking point is your definition of "any serializable object" - as long as the client/server *agree* on the types of messages involved, it'll be fine - but "any" is a bit trickier.

If you have an example model (it doesn't have to be your "real" model), feel free to add it and I'll show how it can be used in this way.

Comment: Can protobuf be used with C#? It doesn't look like it! -- There's also a .NET version, sorry about that :)

Comment: +1 for protobuf, didn't know the framework up to now. Looks interesting

Comment: @tzup there are *at least* 3 different C# protobuf implementations, one of which I cited by name (protobuf-net) and which I'm pretty familiar with ***since I wrote every line***. Or a shorter version: "yes, it can"

Comment: Hi... I looked at some documentation... I'm unclear on how protobuf-net helps me in sending data across a network? Could you provide a small example or a link to some relevant documentation? Thanks :) Edit: I understand that I will need to use the SerializeWithLengthPrefix etc... But then the nature of sockets is that data doesn't always arrive in one piece anyway?

Comment: @Motig I'm assuming you would wrap the socket with a NetworkStream. The WithLengthPrefix variants are able to read the correct amount from a stream allowing a succession of messages without over-reading on any individual message. Re sending data across a network - that pretty much *defines* serialisation/deserialization... Serialize to a stream, deserialize from a stream...

Comment: Hi Marc. I've got protobuf working in a simple test application... It seems to work fine. However, I'm only sending tiny amounts of data so far. To confirm what you just said, then; even if the data was split into multiple packets, DeserializeWithLengthPrefix() would 'hang' the application until all the data was there? If so; then it seems like protobuf-net might be what I was looking for. Would I owe you any money if I then sold a game using it?

Comment: @Motig yes, it will block while it reads the entire message, which is most easily solved by threading. I could write an async version if we really wanted. No you wouldn't owe me anything.

Comment: I would be happy to donate some money if I did end up making a profit, nonetheless. But essentially, no; I would not want an async version. I just wanted to confirm how it worked. Thank you a lot, Marc.